# Link to DetailView from UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, master-detail

I want to allow a user to see the detail about a point on a graph when he touches the point and holds the touch for a certain amount of time.

Touching the point for less than that amount of time will display a dialog box above the point with more information.

**Storyboard**
[image: Storyboard]

I have laid my application out as two tabs. One tab is a graph. The other tab is a master-detail sequence. The user can access DetailView by:

- Clicking on the *Scientist* tab and scrolling through the list of scientists. (Straightforward to do)
- Clicking on the *Ecosystem* tab and selecting a point on a scatter plot. The *Ecosystem* tab loads first. Each point corresponds to one item in the list. **<-- I don't know how to make this linkage**

Answer (score 1):

you can define a scale and divide your whole screen in small small cells and when user "click" or "long press" on any cell you can show the particular message/ info. For example if you are taking a scale of 10px then you can divide you iPhone as below:

[image]

And now when user touch or press any point you can find the corresponding cell and show the popup.